# checkBox if else statement is not working

Tags: android, if-statement, boolean

My if else statement is not working.
The following is my Javacode.

```
 private void displayItem( ) { 

TextView selectedItem = findViewById(R.id.selectionDetail);

 if(selectCoffee=true){ selectedItem.setText("Coffee Selected");


ImageView selectImage = findViewById(R.id.imageView); selectImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.coffee); 

else{ selectedItem.setText("");} 

if (selectIceCream=true){ 
selectedItem.setText("Ice Cream Selected"); 
ImageView selectImage = findViewById(R.id.imageView); selectImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.coffee); } 
else { selectedItem.setText("");} 
}
```

**Please help me, what is the mistake I haven't cared?**

Comment: comparing selectIceCream=true when there is not return method anywhere ? Same with coffee

Comment: please clarify, I am beginner. Is it mandatory to include a return method?

Comment: where did you got that code?

Comment: i have done it by myself

Comment: as Void says, you are just comparing with true and false from a boolean and not returning nothing from checks or not... you are doing it wrong, those booleans dosnt mean nothing

Comment: `=` is assignment and `==` is to compare. When you say `if (item = true)` you are setting `item = true`, not comparing the current value of item to true.

Comment: The checkboxes have click listeners, just implement there what you need

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correct this statement

```
if(selectCoffee=true)
```

with this:

```
if(selectCoffee==true)
```

and same with this :

```
 if (selectIceCream=true)
```

Replace with:

```
 if (selectIceCream==true)
```

use `==` in all if conditions.

Comment: Thanks Suraj. Yes I got my error. It should have == instead of = sign.

I don't know who give negative! I have given + score but it is not countable as I am a new member. In between thankuu very much.

Comment: I marked it but my mark is not being counted as I am a new member

Answer (score 1):

You can not check Boolean value like this: `selectCoffee=true`

Instead do something like this:

```
If(selectCoffee){
//Code here if  coffee selected
}
```